# How to check username and password with database to display error message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a login page(HTML) in dynamic project. I want to check username and password with mysql database and display error message on the same page if username or password are incorrect.
I don't want to use servlet here to display the error page because I want to display error message instead of error page.
How can I achieve this in dynamic webproject.
Can I use javascript, jQuery, JSP, or any combination of these?

Comment: You can use all of those. What server-side language is available to you?

Comment: Javascript validation engines are better to go 
http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/

Comment: AJAX is what you're searching for. JQuery supports it out of the box

Comment: Yeah you are searching for ajax AS REENO said .:)

Comment: People are saying ajax but you need SOME server-based code (php, jsp, perl, coldfusion, aspx, etc) to actually run the query and return the result to the ajax caller.

Comment: Can u help me which one is better? Ajax or jsp?

Comment: How new are you to web languages? Have you ever created a simple `<form>` before asking this question?

Comment: I am very new to web languages. I created a website design.. But i just used html and servlets. In servlets, the error will be displayed in a new page. Now, I want to display the error message on the same page... So, I want to know what are the different options I have. Then, I can learn about them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with JSP but here is an overview of what you need:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
                    // don't let the browser submit the form
                    e.preventDefault();

                    // send form data to JSP page
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'process.jsp',
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(data) {
                            // place message in error box
                            $('#error_box').html(data);

                            // if "Success" then redirect if you would like
                            if(data === 'Success!'){
                                // window.location = 'some other page/website';
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="process.jsp">
            <input type="text" name="username" />
            <input type="password" name="password" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="error_box"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**process.jsp**

```
// I don't know JSP
// use the POST values and check your DB
// Upon success/failure just echo the message
// <%='Success!'%>
// <%='Failed!'%>
```